# Customer session model is not returning customer ID in class which was triggered by `customer_account_create` event

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, event-observer, session

When using the `customer_account_create` event, the session model in my class is not able to return the customer ID using `$this->customerSession->getId();`.

However, for testing purposes, when using the `customer_account_edited` observer event, the session is returning the correct ID of the customer. I am guessing that the session is not fully initialized when using the account creation event.

How can I get the customer ID in my class when using the `customer_account_create` observer event. The session model doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure you can get the customer ID using the `customer_account_create`. I can't even find that event in the Magento 2.4 code (maybe it exists in 2.3).

Check the `customer_register_success` event. Looking at the class:
vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php

It seems very possible to get the customer ID from the observer, because this event is executed once the customer has been created:

```
[...]
     $customer = $this->accountManagement
                ->createAccount($customer, $password, $redirectUrl);

     $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'customer_register_success',
            ['account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer]
     );
[...]
```